# Divide RelativeLayout into half (image and text)

Tags: android, css

I've tried and searched for a while to divide my relative layout of a fragment into 2 halfs without succes. In the end I've managed to separate them but, the image doesn't fill half of the screen as it should and I'm getting some errors when I try to centre the text as shown in the image, so in the end I had to erase the centring of the text in order to run the app. I took an invisible object and placed it in the center on the screen in order to separate it into two halfs but I didn't get the expected result. I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out on this matter. On the first half ( the top one ) I want to be have an image and under it, on the other half, a text that should be centred as shown in the image:

[image: Divided]
. Here is my fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View android:id="@+id/fakeView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/population"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/fakeView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/fakeView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why does this have to be a `RelativeLayout`? Why not a `LinearLayout` where you set the two halves weights to be equal?

Comment: The thing is that I tried before with a LinearLayout too, but I didn't get the expected result. The image didn't fill half of the screen even with fill_parent and I couldn't get the text to be centerd as specified. So, I thought maybe someone would know a way for the RelativeLayout as it's smoother and it'd be better. Of course, if I can't get it to work with a RelativeLayout , a LinearLayout would work too.

Comment: "as it's smoother and it'd be better" -- I have no idea what that means. Splitting a `LinearLayout` in half is fairly simple, see [this layout](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ConfigChange/Bundle/app/src/main/res/layout/main.xml) for an example.

Comment: All right, it worked and I thank you for that! But, how do I get to center the text in such a manner? To have it exactly in the center of the other half ( the text's half ), at the same distance from the top of the half, bottom of the half, right of the half and left of the half.

Comment: `android:gravity="center"` sounds like what you want.

Comment: You're a lifesaver! Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use LinearLayout and layout_weight on both of your views. Set equal value to them. And dont forget to set layout_height to 0 in order for this to work.